# Merging two images *created* in php into one

Tags: php, image, merge

I have the following PHP scripts that output/display as PNG/PHP images:

-image.php

-background.php

I would like to be able to open a third script "main.php" and it shows image.php overlayed onto background.php

I have tried using the common method:

```
    <?php

$url1="image.php"
$url2="background.php";

$dest = imagecreatefrompng($url1);
$src = imagecreatefromjpeg($url2);


imagecopymerge($dest, $src, 10, 9, 0, 0, 181, 180, 100);

header('Content-Type: image/png');
imagepng($dest);

imagedestroy($dest);
imagedestroy($src);

?>
```

But this has not worked (presumably because the cource images are php).

Any ideas on how to get these two images merged? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You need to explain to php that it needs to execute image.php instead of include it in its 'raw' form.
The easiest way that I can think of doing this is by using something like curl_init or file_get_contents and adding the full url to the php script so that you open the file via http and ask the web server to execute it for you.

So change your code to something like this:

```
<?php

$url1= file_get_contents("http://example.com/image.php");
$url2= file_get_contents("http://example.com/background.php");

$dest = imagecreatefrompng($url1);
$src = imagecreatefromjpeg($url2);


imagecopymerge($dest, $src, 10, 9, 0, 0, 181, 180, 100);

header('Content-Type: image/png');
imagepng($dest);

imagedestroy($dest);
imagedestroy($src);

?>
```

HTH,

bovako

Answer (score 0):

You should try use `include` to read file content and then `imagecreatefromstring` to create image:

```
<?php

$handle = imagecreatefromstring(include('image.php'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, it appears to be working now. I did have to change the imagecreate functions from png/JPEG to string (as below):

Thanks again! Saved my mind from going crazy

```
$url1= file_get_contents("http://example.com/image.php");
$url2= file_get_contents("http://example.com/background.php");

$dest = imagecreatefromstring($url1);
$src = imagecreatefromstring($url2);


imagecopymerge($dest, $src, 10, 9, 0, 0, 181, 180, 100);

header('Content-Type: image/png');
imagepng($dest);

imagedestroy($dest);
imagedestroy($src);

?>
```